# How to render math symbols using sympy pretty print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, sympy

I'm using parse_latex from sympy to parse and print latex expressions as output, but some math symbols doesn't seem to render correctly. The below example provides gradient operator symbol,

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex

def main():
    # Define the LaTeX equation string directly
    equation_string = "b_{\\grad} = \\frac{x_c}{2}|\\nabla{c}|^2"

    def parse_latex_to_sympy(latex_string):
        return parse_latex(latex_string)

    def equations(expressions):
        print("Math Equations:")
        print("----------------")
        for idx, expr in enumerate(expressions, start=1):
            latex_string = sp.latex(expr)
            print(f"{idx}.")
            print(sp.pretty(expr, use_unicode=True, wrap_line=False))  # Use unicode characters for formatting
            print()

    # Parse the LaTeX equation string to SymPy expression
    sympy_expression = parse_latex_to_sympy(equation_string)

    # Display the equation
    equations([sympy_expression])

# Call the function
main()
```

the output is a string rather than the math symbol

```
Math Equations:
----------------
1.
           x_{c}          2
b_{grad} = ─────⋅│c⋅nabla│ 
             2
```

Does anyone suggest what might be the issue with this? Any better way to parse latex expressions to have unicode pretty printer in terminal?